# RegEx for decimal number with precision of two

Tags: regex, powershell, decimal

I need a regular expression that accepts only decimal numbers, to two decimals.
I have already tried `^\d{1,}(\.\d{2})?$'` but i do not want it to use the optional group, because that will allow `1` to pass. If take out the optional group, it will not allow `1.00` to pass.

my code:

```
[double]$bookPrice = read-host "Enter book price "
if($bookPrice -notmatch '^\d{1,}(\.\d{2})?$'){
        [console]::beep(500,300)
        Write-Host "invalid"
}
```

Valid:

```
1.00
1.12
```

Invalid:

```
1
1.000000
```

The only thing that I think will solve the problem is changing the variable `$bookPrice`to string, but I do not want to waste a line converting it back to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question here, because once you cast to double, your regex is never going to work on "1.00"

When you convert the string to `[double]$bookPrice`, the trailing zeros vanish. A double doesn't store meaningless digits. If the user types `1.00` the `$bookPrice` variable is just "1" and if the user types `1.10` it's just "1.1"  -- the redundant trailing zeros won't show up when you do -match against a double (you're casting the double back to string).

Of course, if all you're concerned about is the string representation of the number, then you can specify the output formatting like this `"{0:n2}" -f $bookPrice` to guarantee you'll always have two and only two decimal places ...

Answer (score 0):

`[\d]*?[.][\d]{2}(?=[\s\W])`

Written with python in mind, but check out: https://regex101.com/r/lT8xD9/1 for the explanation of what's happening. I think it should do what you're looking for, but I'm also sort of new at this.